# Error: Could not find class file for 'com.test ndk.Hello World'

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am working on android application in which I want to use NDK, for this I have downloaded latest ndk package and make the path in eclipse as well. I am using [this tutorial](https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/hello-world-example-using-ndk-in-android/). On the step of creating header file I am getting following errors, terminal errors are given below:

[image]

My Android project path is : /Users/UsmanKhan/Desktop/NewWS_Emergency/Android_NDK
My NDK folder path is: Macintosh HD/Users/UsmanKhan/Desktop/Android_NDK

[image]

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android_ndk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.testndk.HelloWorld"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please upload your manifest.xml file here

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to run **Android code** with the **java** virtual machine? Android doesn't *run* Java Bytecode. It runs **Dalvik**. You need to run your project on an Android emulator, not with `java`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually i want to use C code in my android project. Can you please guide me that how to make it work for android.

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not build your project. Please follow the step 5 first.

> 5) Open your .java file and write following lines of code. and build
>   the project.

You need to build the project first which will create the class files in bin folders.

To build your project, go to `Project->Build Project` of your eclipse menu bar. Or you can enable automatic build by selecting `Project->Build Automatically` in eclipse menu bar, then your project will build automatically if you change your java file.